# How to show buttons for only first row in mat-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table which displays list of executing Jobs.
Currently I have stop and re-execute buttons in front of all the rows.
Now i want to only show button on first row.
how can i do this?

code for buttons in my mat-table

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
        <button
            mat-icon-button
            (click)="stop_exec_job(element)"
            matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
            [disabled]="element.status == 'Completed' || element.status == 'FINISH'"
        >
            <!-- Edit icon for row -->
            <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
        </button>
        <!-- Delete icon for row -->
        <button
            mat-icon-button
            (click)="re_run_job(element)"
            matTooltip="Re-Run the Job"
            [disabled]="
                element.status == 'RUNNING' ||
                element.status == 'Pending'
            "
        >
            <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">
                cached
            </i>
        </button>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<button *ngIf="index === 0"
  ...>...</button>
```

[ngIf doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)